# How to store image captured from camera in gallery?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, gallery

I want to store images captured from images in gallery. I don't want them to store on sdcard. How to achieve that. I have following code

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);
startActivityForResult(i, CHOOSE_CAMERA_RESULT);
```

What should be `tempuri`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tempuri=Uri.fromFile(getOutputFromCamera());
```

where getOutputFromCamera() is

```
private File getOutputFromCamera() {

    File storageDir = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            AppConstants.FOLDER_NAME);
    if (!storageDir.exists()) {
        if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed to create directory " + storageDir
                    + AppConstants.FOLDER_NAME);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to create Directory",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
    }

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File imageFile = new File(storageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".png");
    return imageFile;
}
```

Where **Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES** is default picture directory and **AppConstants.FOLDER_NAME** is folder name where the image is saved. You can change these according to your needs.